# Quantity not updating in session

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session

I am using my brothers account because my account is not working due to some issues.

I am working on an e-commerce website. My concern is related to quantities.

I have three pages which are `Test1.php` , `Test2.php` and `Test3.php` and one AJAX page which is called as `ajax_cart.php`. and It's handling ADD TO CART with `SESSION`.

Let's talk about `Test1.php` page
I have only 4 products in the database till now and I am displaying only quantity for testing purpose. My quantities will start from 1. The user can increase the quantity or decrease the quantity using Plus(+) and Minus(-).

[image]

Now what I did I increase the quantities of the product from 1 to 4 and clicked on add to cart button. It displays the right quantity in the Top like "`4 view cart`".

[image]

There is no issue with `Test1.php` page. I clicked on `view cart` then page redirect on `Test2.php`.

Let's talk about `Test2.php` page

In this page, I am displaying only the `quantity` and `proceed to check out`. It just for testing. I am getting the right quantity on this page.

[image]

Now what I did, I increase the quantity in a `Test2.php` page from 4 to 6(anything)
[image]

And click on `Proceed to checkout` then the page is redirecting on the Test3.php page but there I am getting my quantity is showing `4` only. Why 4? because of SESSION but my new quantity is 6.

So My issue is, I increase the quantity in the `Test2.php` but my quantity not reflecting in the `Test3.php` page because of the `SESSION`.

I am sharing you the google drive link because I am not able to upload my code here because it's huge.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KfJbjXlzwVIIX6IW9UKQYWHNKJ84P-3G/view?usp=sharing

Would you help me out in this issue?

**ajax_cart.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connection.php');
 $action = $_POST['action'];
 $p_id   = $_POST['p_id'];

if (isset($_POST['quantity'])) {
         echo $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
}

if($action == 'add'){
     if(!empty($p_id)){
           $query = "SELECT p_id, p_images, p_name, p_brandname, p_company, p_packing, p_oldprice, p_currentprice FROM products WHERE p_id=?";
            if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $p_id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($p_id,$p_images, $name, $brandname, $company, $packing, $oldprice, $currentprice);
                $stmt->fetch();
              }
             $product = array(
                "p_id"=>$p_id,
                "p_brandname"=>$brandname,
                "p_currentprice"=>$currentprice,
                "p_total"=>$currentprice*$quantity,
                "p_images"=>$p_images,
                "quantity"=>$quantity
             );
            // print_r($product);
        if(isset($_SESSION['product_cart']) && !empty($_SESSION['product_cart']))
        {
            if(!array_key_exists($p_id,$_SESSION['product_cart']))
            {
                $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id] = $product;
            }
            else{

                     $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['p_total'] += ($currentprice*$quantity);
                     $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['quantity'] += $quantity;
            }       
        }
        else{
          $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id] = $product;
        }
    }   
}
?>
<a class="text-center" href="test2.php">View Cart</a>
```

**Test2.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('connection.php');
 ?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

                <!-- table section ends here -->

                    <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['product_cart'])){?>
                    <form action="test3.php" method="post">
                    <?php  foreach($_SESSION['product_cart'] as $key=>$product):?>
                      <div class="product-snipet">
                                <div class="sp-quantity">
                                    <div class="sp-minus fff"><a class="eee" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="-1">-</a></div>
                                    <div class="sp-input">
                                        <input type="text" class="quntity-input" value="<?php echo $product['quantity'];?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="sp-plus fff"><a class="eee" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="1">+</a></div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="active" value="Proceed to checkout">
                     </form>
                    <?php }else{echo "<h2 style='font-size:22px'>Cart is empty</h2>";}
                    ?>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*increase the product qty*/
  updateTotal();
$('a.eee').click(function() {

  var $productContainer = $(this).closest('div.sp-quantity');
  var $pro_list = $(this).closest('tr.pro-list');
  var productPrice = parseFloat($pro_list.find('span.price_cal').text());
  var $quantityInput = $productContainer.find('input.quntity-input');
  var newQuantity = parseFloat($quantityInput.val()) + parseFloat($(this).data('multi'));

  if (newQuantity >= 1) {
    // Refresh quantity input.
    $quantityInput.val(newQuantity);

    // Refresh total div.
    var lineTotal = productPrice * newQuantity;
    $pro_list.find('td.total_amount').html('&#36;' + lineTotal);
    $pro_list.find('td.total_amount').data('price', lineTotal); //update data-price
  }
  updateTotal();
});

function updateTotal() {
  var subTotal = 0;
  var currencySymbol = "$";
  //start getting the total amounts from each product row.
  //add them as a subtotal.
  $("tr.pro-list > td.total_amount").each(function(index, element) {
    subTotal += parseFloat($(element).data("price")); //more secure to use data!
  });

  var total = subTotal + $("tr.pro-list.ship > td[data-price]").data("price");
  $("tr.pro-list.sub > td.subtotal").html(currencySymbol + "" + subTotal);
  $("tr.pro-list.total > td.total").html(currencySymbol + "" + total);
}

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Test3.php**

```
 <?php 
     if(!empty($_SESSION['product_cart'])): foreach($_SESSION['product_cart'] as $key=>$product): ?>
       <b class="circle-qty"><?php echo $product['quantity'];?></b>
       <input type="hidden" name="o_product_qty[]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity'];?>"> 
       <?php endforeach;?>
       <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: I think you need an freelancer

Comment: Please place the relevant code in the question. No one with any sense is going to download anything from an untrusted Google drive URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you didn't saved the data in session. You have to save it like you did on "Add Cart".
Following are 2 options from my side:

1. you have to use AJAX to save the changes to session. Like the way you did on Test1.php. You have to provide **onclick** to **Plus** or **Minus** actions and use `add_cart(p_id="")` to call ajax_cart.php to save the changes.
2. Save the changes to session in Test3.php via post submit that you are doing now.

**Test2.php**

```html
<?php 
session_start();
include('connection.php');
 ?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

                <!-- table section ends here -->

                    <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['product_cart'])){?>
                    <form action="test3.php" method="post">
                    <?php  foreach($_SESSION['product_cart'] as $key=>$product):?>
                      <div class="product-snipet">
                                <div class="sp-quantity">
                                    <div class="sp-minus fff"><a class="eee" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="-1">-</a></div>
                                    <div class="sp-input">
                                        <input type="text" class="quntity-input" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity'];?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="p_id[]" value="<?php echo $key;?>" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="sp-plus fff"><a class="eee" href="javascript:void(0)" data-multi="1">+</a></div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="active" value="Proceed to checkout">
                     </form>
                    <?php }else{echo "<h2 style='font-size:22px'>Cart is empty</h2>";}
                    ?>
         

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*increase the product qty*/
  updateTotal();
$('a.eee').click(function() {

  var $productContainer = $(this).closest('div.sp-quantity');
  var $pro_list = $(this).closest('tr.pro-list');
  var productPrice = parseFloat($pro_list.find('span.price_cal').text());
  var $quantityInput = $productContainer.find('input.quntity-input');
  var newQuantity = parseFloat($quantityInput.val()) + parseFloat($(this).data('multi'));

  if (newQuantity >= 1) {
    // Refresh quantity input.
    $quantityInput.val(newQuantity);

    // Refresh total div.
    var lineTotal = productPrice * newQuantity;
    $pro_list.find('td.total_amount').html('&#36;' + lineTotal);
    $pro_list.find('td.total_amount').data('price', lineTotal); //update data-price
  }
  updateTotal();
});

function updateTotal() {
  var subTotal = 0;
  var currencySymbol = "$";
  //start getting the total amounts from each product row.
  //add them as a subtotal.
  $("tr.pro-list > td.total_amount").each(function(index, element) {
    subTotal += parseFloat($(element).data("price")); //more secure to use data!
  });

  var total = subTotal + $("tr.pro-list.ship > td[data-price]").data("price");
  $("tr.pro-list.sub > td.subtotal").html(currencySymbol + "" + subTotal);
  $("tr.pro-list.total > td.total").html(currencySymbol + "" + total);
}
 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Test3.php**

```html
<?php 
session_start();
include('connection.php');

if (isset($_POST['quantity']) && isset($_POST['p_id'])) {
 foreach($_POST['p_id'] as $key => $val) {
  if(isset($_SESSION['product_cart']) && isset($_SESSION['product_cart'][$val]))
  {
   $p_id = $val;
   $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$key];
   $currentprice = $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['p_currentprice'];

   $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['p_total'] = ($currentprice*$quantity);
   $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['quantity'] = $quantity;
  }
 }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php 
         if(!empty($_SESSION['product_cart'])): foreach($_SESSION['product_cart'] as $key=>$product): ?>
           <b class="circle-qty"><?php echo $product['quantity'];?></b>
           <input type="hidden" name="o_product_qty[]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity'];?>"> 
           <?php endforeach;?>
           <?php endif;?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I updated my code with your code but a test3.php page. I am getting the error.  Notice: Undefined variable: p_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\example\test3.php on line 7

Comment: As per @Neethu suggested for error, Quantity is showing wrong. I mean In the test1.php I choose 3 and in the test2.php I increase from 3 to 5 and in the test3.php it's displaying 8 which is wrong. It's should display 5.

Comment: Replace `if(isset($_SESSION['product_cart']) && isset($_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]))` with `if(isset($_SESSION['product_cart']) && isset($_SESSION['product_cart'][$val]))`

Comment: Also replace `$_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['p_total'] += ($currentprice*$quantity);` with `$_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['p_total'] = ($currentprice*$quantity);`

**+=** this will add the new value to the existing and thats why u got 8 instead of 5. try now.

Comment: Sorry, It's not working. The same issue, My quantity is 2 and clicked on proceed to checkout and I got 4. I don't know why I am getting it. There might be some issue in the Test3.PHP. You can also try to check with my code.

Comment: In test3.php, replace the php script with below:
`<?php
session_start();
include('connection.php');

if (isset($_POST['quantity']) && isset($_POST['p_id'])) {
 foreach($_POST['p_id'] as $key => $val) {
  if(isset($_SESSION['product_cart']) && isset($_SESSION['product_cart'][$val]))
  {
   $p_id = $val;
   $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$key];
   $currentprice = $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['p_currentprice'];

   $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['p_total'] = ($currentprice*$quantity);
   $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['quantity'] = $quantity;
  }
 }
}
?>`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Yes, It's also working for me. Thank you for the help. Please update the answer.

Comment: @user9437856 Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

At first you dont have name attribute for your form input field.

[image: add name filed]

Change it as following.

Replace your input in test2.php

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" class="quntity-input" value="<?php echo 
$product['quantity'];?>" />
```

Then in test3.php you will be able to access it like that

```
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
```

and you can modify it based on your needs.

To output correct value in test3.php try this without session

```
<input type="hidden" name="o_product_qty[]" value="<?php echo $quantity;?>">
```

And if you really like to use sessions for that you can assign this post value right after session_start() function

[image]

NB! There is no validations so after developing it you should think about sql injection and such stuff

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I want to use the session in the test3.php, because I am displaying all the record which are chosen by the user. Yes, I know about the SQL injection and validation that I will do later.

Comment: Anyway you need that post request. in test3.php after session_start() function assign to your session variable that post request value.

Comment: Can you help me with the code? Please, I tried but it's not working. If user select more then one add to cart than how can I display the quantity values?

Comment: You need to pass array. Your session variable has to be an array. If client adds something u can just push element there.

Comment: That's right, I have to use the array. but how to use when the user changes the quantity? I am getting the right quantity Without changing the quantity but if the user changes the quality then I am not getting the right answer.

Comment: Send index as well for that session variable array from test2.php with that quantity value

Comment: I haven't understood this. Can you explain me with an example?

Answer (score 0):

You were getting undefined index since $p_id was defined inside if and used it in if condition. Please correct it as below.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include('connection.php');

    if (isset($_POST['quantity']) && isset($_POST['p_id'])) {
        foreach($_POST['p_id'] as $key => $val) {
            $p_id   =   $val;
            if(isset($_SESSION['product_cart']) && isset($_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]))
            {
                $quantity   =   $_POST['quantity'][$key];
                $currentprice   =   $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['p_currentprice'];

                $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['p_total'] += ($currentprice*$quantity);
                $_SESSION['product_cart'][$p_id]['quantity'] += $quantity;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <?php 
             if(!empty($_SESSION['product_cart'])): foreach($_SESSION['product_cart'] as $key=>$product): ?>
               <b class="circle-qty"><?php echo $product['quantity'];?></b>
               <input type="hidden" name="o_product_qty[]" value="<?php echo $product['quantity'];?>"> 
               <?php endforeach;?>
               <?php endif;?> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Quantity is showing wrong. I mean In the test1.php I choose 3 and in the test2.php I increase from 3 to 5 and in the test3.php it's displaying 8 which is wrong. It's should display 5.